# Calling in sick confusion

Tags: management, human-resources, manager, sickness

I woke up this morning feeling awful and not able to go into work in fear of collapsing because of dizziness.

I called in but the woman who told me to go in today wasnt in when I asked for her. The employee who answered the phone said they would let her know tomorrow when she is in.

In the handbook it says to speak to a manager when calling in but the manager that asked me to come in isnt there.

Should I call back and ask for another manager or what should I do? This is really stressing me out.

Answer (score 17):

> Should I call back and ask for another manager or what should I do?
>   This is really stressing me out.

Call back and talk to another manager.

This time, ask what you are supposed to do when your normal manager isn't in. Then do that.

Comment: And make a note of the person you spoke to, and the time.

Comment: This might be a bit of an overkill but once you spoke to a manager, email your manager saying that you tried to reach her and couldn't, so you talked to XXX manager just to cover your ass.

Answer (score 10):

If the handbook says "a manager" as opposed to "your manager" then I would say calling back and speaking to or having a message passed to any manager would be a sensible move that would cover your calling in obligations.